# Get the Cartesian in two DataFrame same columns value

Tags: python, pandas, cartesian-product

**Edit and Update**

I changed data table example and I wanted to make as clean as much so I edited my question!!

I have two DataFrames that they are same.

First is `customer_watched` the second is `future_programs`

Each customer has a database watched programs and I have a future list as well so  my idea is to compare name similarity between two DataFrames(it is basic because my programs are same)

I need to compare each table titles `by one by` for similarity .I tried to get a `Cartesian` takes all `title` columns and makes cartesian but data is big and I have so many customers so it is not a good idea.

Here is tables example:

customer_watched:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│                 title                 │                    genre                     │   Time   │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Regret to Inform                      │ Documentary                                  │ 14:04:39 │
│ Fool There Was.                       │ Drama                                        │ 20:29:59 │
│ Hellraiser: Hellseeker                │ Horror                                       │ 5:56:38  │
│ Bride & Prejudice                     │ Romance                                      │ 6:25:13  │
│ Bear, The (Ours, L')                  │ Adventure                                    │ 18:26:25 │
│ Groundstar Conspiracy, The            │ Romance                                      │ 17:28:12 │
│ Love's Long Journey                   │ Romance                                      │ 4:06:29  │
│ Late Bloomers                         │ Comedy                                       │ 5:12:00  │
│ Kings Row                             │ Drama                                        │ 9:55:58  │
│ Human Resources (Ressources humaines) │ Drama                                        │ 22:45:15 │
└───────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

future_programs:

```
┌─────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│            title            │             genre             │   Time   │
├─────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Ronde, La                   │ Drama                         │ 20:20:25 │
│ Safe House                  │ Action                        │ 18:15:58 │
│ Cypher                      │ Action                        │ 12:39:25 │
│ First Love (Primo Amore)    │ Drama                         │ 4:40:08  │
│ Half Light                  │ Romance                       │ 5:23:57  │
│ Waiting for Forever         │ Drama                         │ 7:51:36  │
│ Vice Squad                  │ Action                        │ 13:40:18 │
│ August Mordum's Underground │ Horror                        │ 11:13:35 │
│ Taxi Driver                 │ Crime                         │ 15:00:12 │
│ $ (Dollars)                 │ Comedy                        │ 9:52:49  │
└─────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

The programs titles related with only `genre` so it is pointless when you compare title with other genre titles so need specific cartesian loop.

When I write a customer name my program gives me number of watched programs and top genre, ex:

top_genre

```
title     genre

drama     19
romance   7
comedy    1
```

so we do not have to compare any other titles so this customer likes `drama` so when I compare customer watched and future list I only want to drama titles cartesian list and compare titles.

```
Ex:  


Fool There Was                               -    Ronde, La 
Fool There Was                               -    First Love (Primo Amore)
Fool There Was                               -    Waiting for Forever
Kings Row                                    -    Ronde, La 
Kings Row                                    -    First Love (Primo Amore)
Kings Row                                    -    Waiting for Forever
Human Resources (Ressources humaines)        -    Ronde, La 
Human Resources (Ressources humaines)        -    First Love (Primo Amore)
Human Resources (Ressources humaines)        -    Waiting for Forever
```

The `future_proframs` list is same but `customer_watched` and `top_genre` are different for each customer.

My Question is how can I make a function that take `top_genre` and `customer_watched` and will compare with `future_list` for each customer?

I used this function for cartesian list but as I wrote this makes all title comparing:

```
def cartesian(df1, df2):
    rows = itertools.product(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows())

    df = pd.DataFrame(left.append(right) for (_, left), (_, right) in rows)
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I tried many option but I could not manage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does my answer not work for your data?

Comment: type columns value are string but I gave you a numeric column I was thinking error is coming from there but I got; "None of [['type']] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Why are you passing "type"?